# Expose spark streaming results via REST API

Tags: rest, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Am new to Spark, I built a Spark Streaming application that consumes flume event and run some statistical analysis on them and output the results to the console, am just wondering is there any way to expose my result like a REST Service so i can write a web app that can pull the results from the analysis done by spark and create a visualisation .Any suggestion are welcome .Thanks

Comment: You can send the results of the processing to either HDFS/Kafka/Any other persistent storage, and create a REST API which pulls on demand. Spark isn't suited to be a used as a REST endpoint.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i thought about doing it that way , i was curious if there's a way to avoid persisting the data . Thanks for your help

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov i found this http://livy.io while doing my investigation looks like it can solve the problem, it allows to submit jobs via REST and get the results

Comment: for Visualization you can use Apache Zeppelin which provides integration for Spark  https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.5.5-incubating/tutorial/tutorial.html (Please refer Twitter's sample tweet stream)

Comment: @Bhavesh i have a dashboard that is already monitoring other services i need a Spark rest endpoint that i can call and update my dashboard , Zeppelin wouldn't be an ideal solution so far i think persisting the data and then pull it from the storage as needed in a RESTful fashion is the best solution . Thanks for your input